# How do you delete only specific rows in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which includes `NaN` values for rows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df 

        one       two     three four   five
a  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  bar   True
b       NaN  1.224234  7.823421  bar  False
c -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  bar  False
d       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN   True
e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  bar   True
f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804  bar  False
```

I could drop all `NaN` values using `df.dropna()`

However, I only what to drop certain rows. For example, if there is a `NaN` is the `one` column, then that row should be dropped.

My solution is to create a new DataFrame

```
df[df.one != 'Nan']
```

How else could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `loc` and pass a boolean mask generated from `notnull`:

```
In [107]:
df.loc[df['one'].notnull()]

Out[107]:
        one       two     three four   five
a  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059  bar   True
c -1.135632  1.212112 -0.173215  bar  False
e  0.119209 -1.044236 -0.861849  bar   True
f -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804  bar  False
```

the mask output:

```
In [109]:
df['one'].notnull()

Out[109]:
a     True
b    False
c     True
d    False
e     True
f     True
Name: one, dtype: bool
```

You can't compare `NaN` values using `==` or `!=` as by design `NaN` == `NaN` is `False`

Comment: Could you use `.notnull()` with the entire DataFrame?

Comment: `df.notnull` will return a boolean mask on the entire df, you'd then have to decide how to use this to mask the df, your requirement is just where 'one' column is not null which is what my answer shows